# Possible to create derived properties within database?

Tags: database, mongodb, jscript, derived-class

I have been trying to look at MongoDB but other database may be better or maybe an object abstraction level using script between a relational database and the front end to get objects with derived properties.

What I want is to modify an object class and add derived properties using pre-defined transformation functions from existing data easily without time consuming re-calculation.

For a simple example, I want to derive the average speed of long distance runners in their past 2 races. I will use the derived class structure to build a regression model for analysis.

```
Race
{
                ID = 123
                Distance = 5000
                Date = 1 Jan 2019
}

Running
{
                RunnerID = abc
                RaceID = 123
                Time = 96
}
```

Change base class to add speed

```
Running
{
                RunnerID = abc
                RaceID = 123
                Time = 96
                Speed = Race.Distance / This.Time  (derived from base class)
}
```

Or

```
Running
{
                RunnerID = abc
                RaceID = 123
                Time = 96
                Speed = Race.Distance / This.Time  (derived from base class)
                AvgSpeed = (This.Speed + This.PreviousRace.Speed) / 2  (derived from base class)
}

    }
```

New properties (factors) should be able to be added easily using Jscript or similar and then the modelling engine can use this class structure to do regression and test models.

Is this type of concept possible within any database or would it all need to be created in code?

It is important to generate the new factors quickly and then trying what-if analysis.

Comment: MongoDB is flexible enough to have multiple documents with different structures . You can keep adding records with different structures and Mongo will be happy to oblige.However if you are using any framework like Express  you need to define your model and stick to it.

Comment: Satya, which web frameworks don't need to have a model defined and stick with it?